# How to include additional CSS files in Aurelia?

Tags: css, webpack, aurelia

Ihave a app that opens a new window with content. I need special CSS for that window.

Code for opening the window is this:

```
var Printwindow = window.open("","","width=360,height=188");
    var cssFile = Printwindow.document.createElement("link");
    cssFile.rel = "stylesheet";
    cssFile.type = "text/css";
    cssFile.href = "../../content/label.css";

    Printwindow.document.write("<head>" + cssFile.outerHTML + "</head><body onload='window.print();'>" + this.label.innerHTML + "</body>");
    Printwindow.document.close();
    Printwindow.focus();
```

the label.css is there when i just run it in localhost. But when i build it and eploy it to server it is missing. How can i include this label.css in the bundle so that it can find it?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using webpack, you should reference the file so webpack finds it:

```
cssFile.href = PLATFORM.moduleName("../../content/label.css");
```

and do the import of PLATFORM:

```
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I would recommend that you create a component and compose that within a dialog or new window. This will allow you to avoid building your presentation layer within JS. If you created a custom-component, you could do the following:

```
<template>
 <require from="label.css"></require>
 {Content Here}
</template>
```

You could then compose this into a dialog.

Alternatively, if you're unable to make structural changes, then you should import PLATFORM from aurelia-pal and use it as such:

```
import {PLATFORM} from 'aurelia-pal';
// .. other code here ..
cssFile.href = PLATFORM.moduleName("../../content/label.css");
```

If you are still having issues, then it may be because you need to resolve your production server's base URL.